# Express server returns 200 for routes that have not even been defined

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I have been facing a weird thing for several days and I had no luck of solving that so far. The problem is I have a React.js frontend , Node Express.js backend and MongoDB, when I'm making requests to `/api/users/update-pwd` with proper parameters using `axios`, it doesn't update the password, but it returns 200. Then, I tried some routes such as `/api/users/psosp`. To my surprise, It also returned 200. I couldn't find the reason for that. Any helpful tip is highly appreciated.

```js
Axios.post("/users/update-password",{
       password: n_pwd
}).then(
     res => {
        alert("Password Updated")
     }
).catch(err => {
     console.log(err)
     alert("An error occured")
})
```

Comment: do you have some route having path like /users/:some_param_name? . if yes try to debug in that path.

Comment: Your frontend request is ok. Show your relevant backend code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you don't have code like this in your backend.

```
router.post('/users/:userId',(req,res)=>{
// some operations
res.send();
});

router.post('users/update-password',(req,res)=>{
// some operations
res.send();
});
```

What above does is that it doesn't matter whatever you use in place of *  `/users/*/`
the first route will be called by default

and also make sure that you did not use

```
app.use('*',(req,res)=>{
// some operations
res.send();
})
```

For any API call irrespective of the path the above code will be called.

Comment: what should you have instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try to restrict all routes that have "params" in it like this:

```
router.get('/users/:userId',(req,res)=>{
// some operations
res.send();
});
```

into :

```
router.get('/users/getById/:userId',(req,res)=>{
// some operations
res.send();
});
```

Because `:userId` overrides whatever is written after `/users/` so you have to restrict it with `/getById/` placed before, for exemple.