# Express route returning 200 always with an empty object

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Node and express REST api setup. Generated some api endpoints using https://github.com/diegohaz/rest that work fine but when I add a new route, no matter what, it will return a 200 and an empty object even if I change the return value of the routes function.

Project setup:

Router index

```
import { Router } from 'express'
import user from './user'
import auth from './auth'
import passwordReset from './password-reset'
import manga from './manga'

const router = new Router()

/**
 * @apiDefine master Master access only
 * You must pass `access_token` parameter or a Bearer Token authorization header
 * to access this endpoint.
 */
/**
 * @apiDefine admin Admin access only
 * You must pass `access_token` parameter or a Bearer Token authorization header
 * to access this endpoint.
 */
/**
 * @apiDefine user User access only
 * You must pass `access_token` parameter or a Bearer Token authorization header
 * to access this endpoint.
 */
/**
 * @apiDefine listParams
 * @apiParam {String} [q] Query to search.
 * @apiParam {Number{1..30}} [page=1] Page number.
 * @apiParam {Number{1..100}} [limit=30] Amount of returned items.
 * @apiParam {String[]} [sort=-createdAt] Order of returned items.
 * @apiParam {String[]} [fields] Fields to be returned.
 */
router.use('/users', user)
router.use('/auth', auth)
router.use('/password-resets', passwordReset)
router.use('/manga', manga)

export default router
```

Manga routes defined

```
import { Router } from 'express'
import { middleware as query } from 'querymen'
import { master } from '../../services/passport'
import { index, show, top24 } from './controller'

const router = new Router()

/**
 * @api {get} /manga Retrieve mangas
 * @apiName RetrieveMangas
 * @apiGroup Manga
 * @apiPermission master
 * @apiParam {String} access_token master access token.
 * @apiUse listParams
 * @apiSuccess {Object[]} mangas List of mangas.
 * @apiError {Object} 400 Some parameters may contain invalid values.
 * @apiError 401 master access only.
 */
router.get('/',
  master(),
  query(),
  index)

/**
 * @api {get} /manga/:id Retrieve manga
 * @apiName RetrieveManga
 * @apiGroup Manga
 * @apiPermission master
 * @apiParam {String} access_token master access token.
 * @apiSuccess {Object} manga Manga's data.
 * @apiError {Object} 400 Some parameters may contain invalid values.
 * @apiError 404 Manga not found.
 * @apiError 401 master access only.
 */
router.get('/:id',
  master(),
  show)

/**
 * @api {get} /manga/top24 Retrieve lastest top 24h mangas
 * @apiName RetrieveTop24Mangas
 * @apiGroup Manga
 * @apiPermission master
 * @apiParam {String} access_token master access token.
 * @apiSuccess {Object[]} mangas List of top24 mangas.
 */
router.get('/top24',
  master(),
  top24)

export default router
```

Functions for the routes

```
// const api = require('mangadex-full-api')

export const index = ({ querymen: { query, select, cursor } }, res, next) =>
  res.status(200).json([{ test: 'comon' }])

export const show = ({ params }, res, next) =>
  res.status(200).json({})

export const top24 = ({ querymen: { query, select, cursor } }, res, next) =>
  res.status(200).json([{ test: 'comon' }])
```

Finally, the console log, the route in question is /manga/top24

```
GET /manga/top24?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx 200 0.347 ms - 2
```

Return 200 {}

Infact, I can call any route after /manga such as /manga/blahhvlahd and it will return 200 with {}

As requested, here is the code for the master function, it calls the passport library. Removing the master call does not solve the problem however.

```
export const master = () =>
  passport.authenticate('master', { session: false })
```

Comment: What does `master()` do?

Comment: @eol Master makes the endpoint require a access token in the params

Comment: can you show the detail about master() function ?

Comment: @AdamBishti: As Kyle says, please edit your question and add the code for the `master` function..

Comment: @Kyle I edit my post to include the master function

Comment: No sure if it's related. But top24 controller is trying to get { queryman } from request object without using query middleware in given top24 route.

Comment: Other than that, I don't see any error here. Maybe you can try run server in debug and set break point at top24 controller to check if it even get called.

Comment: Seems like this could be the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61230021/express-server-returns-200-for-routes-that-have-not-even-been-defined